# Cannot find protocol declaration NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I don't understand why errors persist despite what I believe to having correctly imported the required files and frameworks. The core data staple code fits nicely in the `AppDelegate`, but when I now want to use the `NSFetchedResultsController` in my custom `ViewController` I get shown these errors shown below:

[image]

**Here are the frameworks added thus far.**

[image]

**Without importing the files in my custom `viewcontroller`, I tried to fixate the importing the `Prefix-h` file in the `ifdef` section as shown below and still the error is thrown.**

[image]

Can someone pls suggest whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reviewed you using `NSWindowController` means its an `Mac OSX` application and the `CoreData Framework` for `Mac OSX` does not have `NSFetchedResultsController.h` so `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelagete` protocol is not declared here. For option you can review `NSArrayController` So review this tutorial.

[How to Use Cocoa Bindings and Core Data in a Mac App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21752/how-to-use-cocoa-bindings-and-core-data-in-a-mac-app)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Oh my goodness. *sighs* just as I had worried, I did look in the core data files and I couldnt find any NSFetchedResultsController. I thought id post just incase I was missing something. Ok, I'll have a look at your resource and pray that it contains what I need.